# Why is order by not working in my Union query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I'm trying to order by month by doing this query between 3 tables :

```
SELECT NULL AS `inState`, NULL AS `outState`, mb.`isDuplicate`, mb.`questStatus`,   mb.state, mb.`subState`, mb.`recomputedOn`, c.`TSsubmitOn`, c.`submittedOn`, mb.week, mb.month 
FROM metric_backlog mb INNER JOIN `CR` c ON c.crdbid = mb.crdbid 
WHERE (mb.`productName` = 'ecc' AND mb.`releaseName` 
IN ('6.7.3', '6.5.0', '6.7.0', '6.7.1', '6.6.0', '6.7.2', '6.2.0', '6.1.0')) AND mb.month = '1101'

UNION ALL 
SELECT mi.`inState`, mi.`outState`, NULL AS sq, NULL AS ee, NULL AS yy, NULL AS qq,   NULL AS xx, NULL AS mer, NULL AS yi, mi.week, mi.month as monthh
FROM metric_inout mi INNER JOIN `CR` c ON c.crdbid = mi.crdbid 
WHERE mi.month = '1101' AND mi.month != "NULL" AND mi.month IS NOT NULL AND 
mi.`productName` = 'ecc' AND mi.`releaseName` 
IN ('6.7.3', '6.5.0', '6.7.0', '6.7.1', '6.6.0', '6.7.2', '6.2.0', '6.1.0')
ORDER BY mi.month
```

I get the error : Unknown column mi.month in order clause

thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to order the result of the union or just the second subquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error -1054 unknown column e.id in order clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654920/error-1054-unknown-column-e-id-in-order-clause)

Answer (score 0):

try this in the order by :

```
  ORDER BY month
```

instead of select month from second query

```
  SELECT NULL AS `inState`, NULL AS `outState`, mb.`isDuplicate`, mb.`questStatus`,   mb.state, mb.`subState`, mb.`recomputedOn`, c.`TSsubmitOn`, c.`submittedOn`, mb.week, mb.month as month
```

Answer (score 0):

With UNION ALL you select columns with the names gathered from the first select statement. There are no langer tables names associated with these names. So you select: inState, outState, isDuplicate, questStatus, state, subState, recomputedOn, TSsubmitOn, submittedOn, week, and month. (Names from the second - and further SQL statements if any - are completely irrelevant, by the way.)

Hence you cannot order by mi.month. After UNION ALL being applied, the table-associated field "mi.month" is no longer available. Only the unioned field "month" is. You can only order by month.